# Understanding basic recursion using Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having trouble visualizing what actually happens in a recursive function. I've tried drawing activation frames and following the flow of data, but I get lost along the way. The visualizer at PythonTutor.com doesn't help as much as I'd hoped.

Here's a function that determines the number of digits in a number using recursion.

```
def digits(x):
    if x > 0:
        return 1 + digits(x // 10)
    else:
        return 0
```

Why is the 1 the only things that "survives" from one activation frame to another?

Comment: Add a couple print statements and print the values prior to the return statement. The hardest part about recursion is remembering that it unwinds itself. Try looking at a few of these examples to see if one clicks for you: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Recursions/recursions.html  -- I think recognizing a recursive problem is 1/2 the battle in understanding recursion

Comment: Negative numbers have digits too

Comment: Also you can learn what is tail recursion which is optimised in most of the modern languages but apparently python did not do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I am to consider `x = 20`, the flow would be as follows:

```
End:   result = 2 <-----------.
                              |      +
Start: digits(20) ==> returns 1 <-----------.
                          +                 |      +  
                      digits(2) ==> returns 1 <-----------.
                                        +                 |
                                    digits(0) ==> returns 0
```

Answer (score 0):

With recursion, it's often useful to start with the base case. You can work it out on paper easily enough.

```
digits(0)
x = 0
if x > 0 # false
return 0
digits(0) == 0

digits(1)
x = 1
if x > 0 # true
return 1 + digits(1 // 10)
return 1 + digits(0) # 1//10==0
return 1 + 0  # digits(0)==0
return 1
digits(1) == 1

...

digits(10)
x = 10
x > 0 # true
return 1 + digits(10 // 10)
return 1 + digits(1)
return 1 + 1
return 2
digits(10) == 2
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Take digits(10) as an example:

```
digits(10):
    if 10 > 0:
        return 1 + digits(10 // 10)
    <==>return 1 + digits(1)
    <==>return 1 + 
                    if 1 > 0:
                        return 1 + digits(1 // 10)
                    <==>return 1 + digits(0)
                    <==>return 1 + 
                                    if 0 > 0:
                                        return 1 + digits(0 // 10) 
                                    else:
                                        return 0
                    else:
                        return 0
    else:
        return 0
```

- **digits(0)** returns 0;
- **digits(1 // 10)** returns 1 + **digits(0)** = 1 + 0,
- **digits(10)** returns 1 + **digits(1 // 10)** = 1 + 1 + 0 = 2